# Apply jQuery function to multiple elements with same class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a web page that has multiple sliders on, all with the class '.viewer'

If I add my jQuery

```
   $('.viewer').carousel('.viewer #simplePrevious', '.viewer #simpleNext');
```

This doesnt work, Is this because it doesnt know what slider this applies too? Should it not apply to all .viewer elements on the page?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You should use the jQuery method `each()`:

```
$('.viewer').each(function() {
    $(this).carousel('.viewer #simplePrevious', '.viewer #simpleNext');
});
```

Check the online doc for more information: http://api.jquery.com/each/

Hope this helps mate.

Comment: Ahh brilliant, thanks a lot @Littm, Ill read up on that now but its working great!